# Some book to learn ODE, theory and computations

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not so good with computations, does someone know some book that has good computational tutorials and the basic theory of any introductory course?

Comment: Computations of *what*? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Daniel, you asked 8 questions so far, and you haven't accepted any answers. Please accept the answers that were most helpful by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left of them. You could also consider registering your account, so that you can vote the answers up in order to "reward" people who invested some time in trying to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations Earl A. Coddington is a good book and covers basics from the beginning. You can also see this link for many more books.

- http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/#Differential Equations

Simmons G.F, also has a very good book written on differential equations.